# 404 Page not found error after adding 's' in 'http' in Settings

Tags: 404-error, ssl, https

My site would display the message `This connection is not private` when I visited the https version. Trying to fix this I went to the Wordpress admin panel and to Settings and added a "s" to the two URL fields there as suggested [here](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/#implementing-https-for-wordpress).

Once I did that all pages including wp-admin display the `404 Page not found error`. I was trying to see if I can reverse this via Filezilla but I am not sure what file to look at.

How can I fix the 404 error?

Update: 
I was able to remove the 's' from 'https' n cPanel - Databases - phpMyAdmin. There I clicked on my database and then on the wp_options table. Clicking on edit for the rows with `option_value` `siteurl` and `home` lets you edit the `option_value` field where you can remove the 's'.

Comment: Did you install SSL certificate for your domain? You should be able to acquire a free one using letsecrypt service. Check with your hosting provider.

Comment: @Zlatev I am on hostgator and I haven't installed any SSL certificate. I thought hostgator implemented that by default.

Comment: no, unfortunately it doesn't work like that. Most decent hosting providers already integrated with "let's encrypt" but still require you to manually enable that integration.

Comment: Hostgator does not support let's encrypt. If you want SSL you'll need to pay for it, or consider another provider.